# '?doing_wp_cron='

Tags: php, wordpress, url, blogs

Why sometimes when you open any link in a WordPress based website, the link is followed by:

`?doing_wp_cron=...` and the `value`.

What's that and how can I definitely remove it for good?

Comment: I never see this. Any example that you can share?

Comment: No it kinda happens randomly. I click the link of a post or the link of the homepage and it goes with that on the bottom of the link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like "you" have enabled some background processing like a task scheduler on wordpress config (`wp-config.php`).

Try to find and change the value of `ALTERNATE_WP_CRON` from *TRUE* to *FALSE*

Or add `define('DISABLE_CRON', true);`

Comment: I've done it and it seems it worked, but can you tell me what ALTERNATE_WP_CRON is and why should I enable it?

Comment: You shouldn't enable it. You should disable it to prevent `doing_wp_cron` in your URLs. More info: | http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Alternative_Cron

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too. And I found an option by writing a redirect in your .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)doing_wp_cron= [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

So, the piece of the code does redirect of all pages with the "doing_wp_cron" to its original URL. I haven't found any side effects so far.

Answer (score 1):

set **DISABLE_WP_CRON** to **true** in **wp-config.php** as:

define( 'DISABLE_WP_CRON', true );

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have `ALTERNATE_WP_CRON` defined in your `wp-config.php` file. Anyway, it might be enabled from third-party plugin.